# How to draw a point at an exact location with spplot?

Tags: shapefile, r

I imported a Shapefile holding a quite detailed world map from: http://www.diva-gis.org

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
world = readOGR('./countries_shp/', 'countries')
```

Using R with the sp-Packages, plotting is really easy:

```
spplot(world, 'UNREG2')
plot(world)
```

---

Now I want to

- draw a customizable grid
- add points derived from coordinates

For example importing coordinates of Vienna (48°12′32″N 16°22′21″E) can be done using char2dms of the sp-package:

```
vienna.N = char2dms("48d12'32\"N")
vienna.E = char2dms("16d22'21\"E")
```

But how can a **draw a point at this exact location** on my map?

---

Also adding a grid is straight forward:

```
plot(gridlines(world), add=TRUE)
```

assuming, that the last plot was created with "plot(world)". 
**How can this be achieved with the spplot output?**

Comment: Just posting a link to some useful `R` tricks from a few months ago here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3310/what-is-the-most-useful-spatial-r-trick You can plot points with `dismo` and `ggplot2` (I don't know how to do it in `sp`).

Comment: http://r-spatial.sourceforge.net/gallery/#fig06.R gives an example. You can't mix base graphics with spplot (grid) if that is what your asking.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! I do not want to mix base and sp (lattice) graphics, but draw a customizable grid over/on an spplot. It is very easy using base-graphics (plot) so there just has to be a similar way for the sp package?

Comment: This sounds like a `lattice` question, pure and simple: you might get a fast authoritative answer over on SO.

Comment: I will try to get an answer there, but I think that the the transformation/projection of the grid is actually a GIS related topic...

Comment: Please try to use meaningful thread titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to print a point for Vienna on the map.

Importing the coordinates from WikiPedia into R:

```
vienna.N = char2dms("48d12'32\"N")
vienna.E = char2dms("16d22'21\"E")
```

Building a sp-object

```
vienna.coord = data.frame(
        name='Vienna', 
        x=as.numeric(vienna.E), 
        y=as.numeric(vienna.N)
)
coordinates(vienna.coord) = c('x', 'y')
```

The projection is taken from http://toolserver.org/~geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Vienna&params=48_12_32_N_16_22_21_E_type:city_region:AT where the WikiPedia article links to:

```
proj4string(vienna.coord) = '+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84'
```

Printing this object gives the numeric representation which equals exactly the data from mentioned website:

```
> vienna.coord
         coordinates   name
1 (16.3725, 48.2089) Vienna
```

The resulting

```
> class(vienna.coord)[1]
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
```

can be used with base- and sp-graphics. First we transform the projection to the one used in the Diva worldmap:

```
vienna.coord = spTransform(vienna.coord, CRS(proj4string(world)))
```

Then a plot for Europe can be produced:

```
spplot(world, 'COUNTRY', colorkey=FALSE, 
    xlim=c(-24.5, 69.5), ylim=c(26.6, 71.2),
    sp.layout = c('sp.points', vienna.coord, col='red', pch=16),
    par.settings = list(panel.background=list(col='lightblue')),
    col.regions = rep('white', length(levels(world$COUNTRY)))
)
```

[image: world map with red dot for Vienna]

Comment: Very cool! It looks beautiful also.

Answer (score 0):

The part of my questions concerning 'grids' solved itself.

Obviously, the function gridlines generates a rectangular grid for the given projection. A distortion can only be seen after projecting the grid. This might help using 2 projections in one map.