# Simple thematic mapping of shapefile using Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, visualisation, matplotlib

I wish to visualize geographical data in Python, without using ArcGIS/ArcPy, and make a map.

On the internet I found **[how to make a thematic map using Python](http://danieljlewis.org/2010/05/25/a-thematic-map-in-python/)**:

Here is some code that I tried:

```
import shpUtils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shpRecords = shpUtils.loadShapefile('C:\\Users\\shapefile.shp')

for i in range(0,len(shpRecords)):
    x = []
    y = []
    for j in range(0,len(shpRecords[i]['shp_data']['parts'][0]['points'])):

    tempx = float(shpRecords[i]['shp_data']['parts'][0]['points'][j]['x'])
    tempy = float(shpRecords[i]['shp_data']['parts'][0]['points'][j]['y'])
    x.append(tempx)
    y.append(tempy)
    plt.fill(x,y)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.title("Testing")
plt.show()
```

However, when I run this, it gives me random colors.

If I want to visualise one certain column of my shapefile, how can I implement this using similar code?

This is very unclear in the link provided above where he only discusses the usage of colors...

Would I perhaps need extra modules to accomplish this, like **[descartes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes)** and **[PySAL](http://pysal.readthedocs.org/en/v1.7/)**?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I do not know ArcPy, but I work with shapefiles and raster in Python for years

1. For processing shapefiles in Python, there are many modules like [osgeo/ogr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL), [Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona), [Pysal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySAL/) or [Pyshp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp) ([shpUtils](http://indiemaps.com/blog/2008/03/easy-shapefile-loading-in-python/) is one of them and
   not the most used), and others, see [Pypi: GIS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&show=all&c=391) and examples on gis.stackexchange and many examples on the Web (not only in English). Most of them are much older than ArcPy (or arcgisscripting)...
2. for processing raster you can use [osgeo/gdal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL), the standard
3. For processing geospatial geometries, there is [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely)
4. For plotting the geometries you can use [matplotlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib) and possibly [descartes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes), "extension" of matplotlib for areas, but also many, many other modules, see  [Pypi: Plotting](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=plotting&submit=search) and modules like [mayavi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mayavi) for 3D representation (matplotlib also)
5. There are also modules like  [mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) which give you directly the possibilities of 1) read a shapefile and 4) plotting with the module [Pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/).

After that, it's like a GIS:

- you use the modules 1) to open, save the shapefiles and carry out the treatments with other modules like numpy or scipy, if you want.
- you can use shapely for manipulation and analysis of the geometric objects (buffer, etc.).
- you can use matplotlib to plot the geometries, but matplotlib do not know what you want to plot. It is your work with modules 1) or 3) to specify what to plot (attributes, etc,.) and how.

> If I want to visualise one certain column of my shapefile, how can I implement this in the code?

So, you must learn matplotib and the other modules. You have to learn ArcPy, it's the same...(there are lots of excellent tutorials on the web, especially for matplolib, and it's easier that ArcPy because it is pure Python).

Some examples with Python only

[image]

Geological map (polygon shapefile) with colors based on an attribute

[image]

3D Points (PointZ shapefile) with color based on an attribute

[image]

3D points (Point shapefile with z as attribute) and 3D line (PolyLineZ shapefile) on a DEM, and on a raster draped onto the DEM surface.

[image]

Topographic profile  with z values and colors based on attributes (geological formations = Cross section) of the original shapefile (Polyline shapefile)

[image]

DEM (GeoTIFF) with the module Mayavi2

[image]

DEM (ESRI ascii grid, .asc) and Point shapefiles (with z as attribute) with the module [visvis](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/)

[image]

Boreholes (3D buffer of a polylineZ with colors based on an attribute (geological formations), with a grid surface calculated with the modules numpy and matplotlib from a points shapefile (with z as an attribute), visualized with the module [visvis](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/)

Answer (score 18):

I've had similar problems where I want to visualize shapefiles quickly, and I've always found the Matplotlib way quite a lengthy way to accomplish such a small task. Instead I developed the ["Python Geographic Visualizer" module](http://thepythongischallenge.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/first-milestone-reached-the-visualizing-library-is-now-complete/), or GeoVis for short. **Update:** v0.2.0 is now out with lots of new functionality.

With it visualizing shapefiles couldn't be easier:

```
import geovis
geovis.ViewShapefile("C:/yourshapefile.shp")
```

Voila, you map pops up as an image in a Tkinter window and you can also save the map to an image file. Styling, coloring, and adding multiple layers to a map is also possible, and in the newest version you can also **classify based on attributes** and **zoom** in to a particular region. In the map below geovis loaded and categorically colored all the world's GADM provinces in about 5 minutes. You can [download GeoVis from here](http://thepythongischallenge.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/first-milestone-reached-the-visualizing-library-is-now-complete/), where you can also read more about how to use it.

[image]

The aim is on easy installation as much as ease-of-use, so GeoVis can be used by anyone who has Python and does not require any other modules since it can use the builtin Tkinter Canvas as a renderer. But it is highly recommended that you have or get either Aggdraw, PIL, or PyCairo, which can also be used as renderers and are much faster and higher quality.

Backdraw is your shapefile has to be unprojected with lat/long coordinate system--it doesn't yet handle projections or transformations.

Answer (score 14):

I came across a number of tutorials dealing with this topic that I wanted to share:

- [So You’d Like To Make a Map Using Python](http://sensitivecities.com/so-youd-like-to-make-a-map-using-python-EN.html) - Stephan Hügel

  [image: Choropleth map]
- [How to Make a US County Thematic Map Using Free Tools](https://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/) - Nathan Yau

  [image: Another choropleth map]
- [A Thematic Map in Python](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20141216050531/http://danieljlewis.org/2010/05/25/a-thematic-map-in-python) - Daniel Lewis
- [Creating Map Visualizations in <10 lines of Python](http://wrobstory.github.io/2013/04/python-maps-choropleth.html) - Rob Story

  [image: Yet another choropleth map]

You might also consider using R: [How to create an attractive choropleth map in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/43534/753)

Answer (score 2):

**In 2019** the simplest way to make a thematic map from a shapefile in python, is **geopandas**.

An example from the documentation: http://geopandas.org/mapping.html

```
import geopandas
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world['gdp_per_cap'] = world.gdp_md_est / world.pop_est
world.plot(column='gdp_per_cap')
```