# Offline Python or C++ library for plotting locations on map?

Tags: python, c++, geolocation, plotter

I'd like to plot locations using longitude and latitude coordinates using Python or C++, is there a good library for such a task?

I know that [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) is an option, I'm wondering if there are any others?

Comment: see [Visualize shapefile in Python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61862/visualize-shapefile-in-python/61868#61868)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapnik is a c++ toolkit for making maps and has python bindings – http://mapnik.org

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for something that's really easy to use and your lat/long data come from a shapefile, you could check out the [Python Geographic Visualizer (GeoVis) module](http://thepythongischallenge.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/first-milestone-reached-the-visualizing-library-is-now-complete/). It has no dependencies, requires no installation, and is very easy to use. In the newest version you can also **zoom** in on specific areas and symbolize based on **attribute classification**:

```
import geovis
# 1 SETUP
geovis.SetMapZoom(x2x=[0,180],y2y=[0,90])
# 2 DATA
countrylayer = geovis.Layer("C:/polygons_shapefile.shp")
countrylayer.AddClassification(symboltype="fillcolor", valuefield="pop_est", symbolrange=[geovis.Color("white"),geovis.Color("red", intensity=0.9, brightness=0.8),geovis.Color("red", intensity=0.9, brightness=0.5)], classifytype="natural breaks", nrclasses=3)
# 3 MAP
newmap = geovis.NewMap()
newmap.AddToMap(countrylayer)
newmap.AddLegend(countrylayer, upperleft=(0.03,0.15), bottomright=(0.6,0.4))
newmap.AddText(relx=0.5, rely=0.05, text="Population, by Country", textsize=0.1, textanchor="n", textboxfillcolor=geovis.Color("white"))
newmap.ViewMap()
```

...will show you a screen with something like this about 2 seconds later...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try mapnik if you really need this to be done in python otherwise use http://www.mapsdata.co.uk to plot your geo-spatial data on map. It support variety of gis formats including lat/lon.

Answer (score 1):

Then there's the [CartoPy](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/) library from the MetOffice. Based on matplotlib, with support for Shapely.

There was a presentation on it at FOSS4G in Nottigham, but I can't seem to find the recording on YouTube yet