# Visualizing 3D Polygon Layer Stack using QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d

Is there a way, or plugin, to visualize a 3D polygon layer stack in QGIS?

I have looked at NViz, but it only seems to work for rasters.

I have a building floor plan with Z info for each floor.  In ArcScene you can import the data and it will "stack" the layers in the Z axis.  I am hoping to be able to complete this in something other than Esri.

[image: 3D Polygon Layer Stack]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as easy as with ArcGIS but you can use;

- Nviz from the GRASS plugin (cf. Micha comment) but you need to know GRASS GIS (look at the illustrations in [GRASS-Wiki: Vector 3D polygons](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Help_with_3D#Vector_3D_polygons) indicated by Micha).

Some geological examples:

[image]

2 polygonZ layers and a raster (2D) draped over DEM (3D)

[image]

extruded volume from the two layers

[image]

Boreholes extruded from circular PolygonZ features (tubes) and a PolygonZ layer (red)

- Python in the Python console with modules as [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) or [visvis](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/) (look at [Visualize shapefile in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61862/visualize-shapefile-in-python/61868#61868))

[image]