# Plotting 3D Data using Python?

Tags: python, 3d, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a Uniform Grid of 1KMx1KM squares as a shapefile with population data in each grid in a specific column as an integer.  I would like to extrude each polygon based on the population and export the whole dataset using a python library.  ArcScene can do this, but ArcPy can't hook into that program.

Can someone recommend a python package to do this?

It doesn't have to be dependent on ArcGIS Desktop.

I was looking at matplotlib, but I can't figure out how to create 3D bar graphs.

Comment: There is a function to do it in mayavi: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#barchart

Answer (score 1):

It is only necessary to learn [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) using the examples provided.

- as [mplot3d example code: hist3d_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html):

[image]

or on StackOverFlow:

- [how to make a 3d effect on bars in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501771/how-to-make-a-3d-effect-on-bars-in-matplotlib)
- [Plotting 3D Polygons in python-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622057/plotting-3d-polygons-in-python-matplotlib)

You only must adapt the script to your grid (look at [Visualize shapefile in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61862/visualize-shapefile-in-python/61868#61868))

As Kelsey says, you can also use [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html)   or [visvis](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/)