# Python with ArcCatalog for Table or Geography view?

Tags: arcpy, arccatalog

Is there a way to automate the preview tab in Arc Catalog using Python?  Say if I wanted to preview the geography of a feature class where I have the path and just don't really want to connect to the folder or database, is this possible?

This preview would access the preview tab in ArcCatalog for desktop. Since the application has to be open, I was wondering if there is a way to automate these workflows, kind of like arcpy.mapping.

Comment: What would this "Preview via ArcPy" look like?  Writing something to create a PDF, JPG, etc would be relatively straightforward.

Comment: check out this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61862/simple-thematic-mapping-of-shapefile-using-python