# How to apply log scale when plotting sf data?

Tags: r, sf

I want to plot some `sf` data, similar to this example:

```
library (sf)

fishnet <- st_make_grid ()
n <- length (fishnet)
vals <- rlnorm (n)
fishnet <- st_sf (fishnet)
fishnet <- cbind (fishnet, vals)

c_ramp <- colorRampPalette (c ("azure", "yellow", "red"))
plot (fishnet, pal  = c_ramp)
```

I want to use a log scale for the legend and color scheme, but the `plot` function doesn't seem to support log scale out of the box. Is there any painless way around that?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17374/80215)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at the code underlying the `plot_sf` function, it seems like the path of least resistance is to just create a new column with the log transformed values. If one could call *y* separately you could transform the values on the fly but, currently the plot generic is not written in that way.

```
fishnet$log.vals <- log(fishnet$vals)
plot(fishnet[,"log.vals"], pal  = c_ramp)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `sf` package [documentation](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/plot.html), the `plot` method for `sf`
objects have and argument (or parameter) called `logz`, which has as default `FALSE`. If you set `logz = TRUE`, the variable that you are trying to plot is displayed on the log-scale.
You can find an example below:

`plot(fishnet["vals"], logz = TRUE)`

Comment: This answer is quite sparse, and could use a documentation reference and a few sentences to frame it as a high-quality answer.

Comment: Just included the requested information.