# Draw lines from points

Tags: arcgis-9.3, polyline-creation, geometry-conversion

Please any body help me for creating lines from points in electric network for instance electric poles are there in point feature with "polename" field like "P01", "P02", "P03" etc. I need a tool that create lines on Target (Feature Class) from P01 to P02 then P02 to P03 in continue.

Comment: There are several other questions that address this on the site, I would suggest looking at this link as several of them are listed, http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=lines

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a script that will automatically draw lines from one point to multiple destination points? (ArcMap 9.3)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/how-to-write-a-script-that-will-automatically-draw-lines-from-one-point-to-multip)

Answer (score 3):

You could try Hawth's Tools 'Convert Locations to Paths' tool.  Same concept.

Comment: http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/locstopath.php

Answer (score 1):

This link points to an ArcScript on ESRI's website.  It is a python script that looks like it was turned into the tool that @PolyGeo references in ArcGIS 10.

It requires that you have an ID field that links the points you want to convert to lines, so you will have the following:

Point Name ID
PO1 1
PO2 1
PO3 2
PO4 2
PO5 2

The key is that if you want PO1 to also appear in Line 2, you will have to repeat it in the shapefile like this:
PO1 1
PO2 1
PO3 2
PO4 2
PO5 2
PO1 2

Here is the link to that ArcScript:  [Points to Lines](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15945)

There used to be a script that took this a step further and used 2 files.  The first was a point feature class like above, where each point had a unique identifier.  The 2nd file was a table that defined the lines based on point id's:
ID Start End
1 PO1 PO2
2 PO1 PO3
3 PO2 PO3
etc
I could not find the script for this one though, but it might give you a starting point.
Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Points To Line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Points_To_Line/00170000003s000000/) tool in ArcGIS 10 that may do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply, presently i am using ArcGis 9.3 i also have xtool where its having "Make one polyline from points" which create a line from points according to OBJECTID. So if P03 is first point and P01 is second point and P02 is third point then a line also create from point P03 to P01 and from P01 to P02, but i want a line from P01 to P02, P02 to P03